# Django not displaying error traceback to browser - just 500 page

Tags: django

I have DEBUG, TEMPLATE_DEBUG and DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS set to true, and there are no tracebacks being displayed to the browser?

Comment: How do you know that Django is even being invoked?

Comment: Further to Ignacio's point, check your logs.

Comment: Check if it is Django's 500 or web server's one. If you have error in one of your middlewares, it can avoid Django's logging framework and cause server to show 500 itself.

Comment: I can access some pages - they render correctly.  Some other pages (dynamic) throw a 500 page at me with no traceback.  Where are Django log files located on a Windows machine?

Comment: You need to learn how to do basic debugging before we can help you with your actual problem

Answer (score 2):

The following is required in `settings` module in order to display diagnostic page after errors:

- `DEBUG` is True
- The client (web browser) is connected from localhost or from any IP address listed in `INTERNAL_IPS`.
- The variable `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` contains `"django.core.context_processors.debug"` or is left on the default value.

You can distinguish the web server's error 500 page from Django's error page easy by different text like this:
"... There's been an error. It's been reported..." (This is from the default template.) 
 if you do `import handler500 from django.conf.urls` (or django.conf.urls.defaults in old Django) in the main urlconf.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an error in your middleware in process_request before you can get to the error page. Although, that you could access some pages would suggest that this is not the problem.

Comment: This hint was really helpful for me especially because I did not receive any traceback from bug inside my custom middleware. Indeed a very specific or rare error but nevertheless thanks a lot to the year 2012 ^^

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
set DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

Answer (score -1):

comment **DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=True**, this should work. Please try.

Comment: The question already states that this setting is set to True.